# Is there a median tool for colours? (Median between 2 colours)

Tags: tools, pixel, pixel-art, image-sprite

I'm working on a pixel sprite and I have 2 coloured pixels with 1 empty pixel gap between them. Is there any way (tool) to fill in the missing pixel with the mixture of the 2 that are filled?

Comment: What software are you working in?

Comment: For blending colors I like chroma.js a lot: https://vis4.net/labs/multihue/#colors=#FF0000,#FFFF00|steps=5|bez=1|coL=1 Maybe this helps in your case, too...

Comment: The result in general depends on your color space. Taking the average RGB value will not give you the same color as taking the average HSV color.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the exact colour code might depend on your current colour space, as mentioned in the comments. This method is colour-space agnostic and whould work in most software that supports layers.

1. Draw a pixel of colour A on a new layer;
2. Add a second layer on top of that, and draw a pixel of colour B exactly on top of pixel A;
3. Reduce layer B's opacity to 50%;
4. Merge the two layers;
5. Sample the resulting pixel's colour. That is the colour you are looking for.

Alternatively, you could also draw directly over pixel A in layer A with a 50% opaque brush in colour B to get the same effect. Faster, but less intuitive.

Comment: Err, now the color that is dependent on color model is the median value. Color has a good enough definition to actually have a median color. Easiest way to compute this though is to work in a device independent colorspace. Also nitpicky but you havent actually computed the median but the average.

Comment: @joojaa *shrug* This works 